firestore undefine the import

This is the error that I have,
The firestoe undefine import

The error show in the debug console:
Undefine part
`package io.flutter.plugins.firebase.firestore.streamhandler;
import static    io.flutter.plugins.firebase.firestore.FlutterFirebaseFirestorePlugin.DEFAULT_ERROR_CODE           ;

import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentChange;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.ListenerRegistration;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.MetadataChanges;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.Query;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.EventChannel.EventSink;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.EventChannel.StreamHandler;
import io.flutter.plugins.firebase.firestore.utils.ExceptionConverter;
import io.flutter.plugins.firebase.firestore.utils.PigeonParser;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Map;`

Expect to Define the import of the cloud_firestore. There no error ,but after I run the project they show all the error above
